# List items until empty gets returns the filled Array - doesn't continuously fill Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to make something that allows me to run list a lot of words and then returns a sorted array when I press Enter without having listed a string. Right now, the prompt lets me type two lines, then returns the array with only the last word added and then loops back and starts again, instead of continuously adding words to the array.

```
def stuffsky
  other_one=[]
  puts "What would you like to add to the message? type a word please, then press Enter"
  while true 
    if gets.chomp != "\n"
      other_one.push(gets)
    else 
      break
    end
    puts other_one
  end
end

stuffsky
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: I'm asking why running this code does not make the array fill with words as long as you continue adding words on every new line. Also, asking how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're trying to do something like this?

```
def stuffsky
  other_one = []
  puts "What would you like to add to the message? type a word please, then press Enter"

  while true 

    word = gets.chomp
    break if word == ""

    other_one.push(word)

    puts "other_one: #{ other_one.join(' ') }"
  end

  other_one
end

puts "stuffsky: #{ stuffsky }"
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
foo
other_one: foo
bar
other_one: foo bar
baz
other_one: foo bar baz

stuffsky: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

The problem is you're not remembering your strings returned by `gets` in:

```
if gets.chomp != ""
  other_one.push(gets)
else 
  break
end
```

Plus your logic is painful. Reverse the logic so you break when your word is empty, otherwise continue.

Comment: BTW thanks very much! I think I see what you meant about the flawed logic - its much easier to just have the break immediately after the gets if it does ="" as opposed to breaking if the gets does not receive input being part of the while loop logic.

Comment: It's not just that the break is after it, it's also the use of `!= ""`. We tend to speak using negative terms, but stating logic in a positive way often makes it clearer and more concise; In other words, `break if word == ""` is easier on the brain than `if word != "" ... break` and allowed me to simplify the rest of the expression.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any good books that help improve logic for programmers?

Comment: I think reading through the "Perl Best Practices" book is a good start, or read through the documentation on the PBP module for Perl. The thinking behind the practices is good to understand. Then you can make decisions for your own coding practices and be aware of the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you reference `gets`, you're actually calling a method that reads in a line of input from the user and returns it. So the first time when you say `gets.chomp != "\n"` Ruby reads in a line of input to check against your condition, and then the second time when you say `other_one.push(gets)` Ruby reads in a second line of input to add to `other_one`. So you can fix this by only calling `gets` once per loop.

There are also a few minor code quality / readability issues with your code. I'd probably do it like this:

```
# Extract line getter to seperate method
def gets_lines
  result = []
  loop do # Use loop instead of while true
    line = gets.chomp # Note: chomp gets rid of the newline at the end of the string
    break if line.empty? # A bit more readable than your other condition
    result << line
  end
  return result
end

def stuffsky
  puts "What would you like to add to the message? type a word please, then press Enter"
  puts gets_lines.sort # You forgot to sort the array in your code
end
stuffsky
```

Sample run:

```
What would you like to add to the message? type a word please, then press Enter
Apple
Orange
Aardvark
Lion    
Tiger

Aardvark
Apple
Lion
Orange
Tiger
```